# Swift - Configuring different cells the same way

Tags: swift, uitableview, generics, protocols, associated-types

Hey I got ConfigurationType protocol

```
protocol ConfigurationType {}
```

and my own cell class

```
class ConfigurableCell<T: ConfigurationType>: UITableViewCell {
    func configure(with config: T) {}
}
```

All my cells inherit from ConfigurableCell and I want to create CellModules, which my tableView would use.

```
protocol CellModule {
    associatedtype Config: ConfigurationType
    associatedtype Cell: ConfigurableCell<Config>
    var config: Config { get set }
}
extension CellModule {
    init(_ config: Config) {
        self.config = config
    }
    func dequeueCell(_ tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell() as Cell
        cell.configure(with: config)
        return cell
    }
}
```

goal is to create module for cell like this

```
struct GoalTitleCellModule: CellModule {
    typealias Cell = GoalTitleCell
    var config: GoalTitleConfiguration
}
```

but xcode complain "Type 'GoalTitleCellModule' does not conform to protocol 'CellModule'".

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Making CellModule protocol visible to Objective-C and changing GoalTitleCellModule type to class will solve your problem.

Take a look here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-55